# How to dynamically create a DOM target for React.createPortal using styled-components?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am using `React.createPortal` to create a component that is to be inserted into a target called `toast-container`. Currently, the only way to define this target is to hard-code `<div id="toast-container" />` directly in my .html file. I am using `styled-components` across my application and I need a way to create this `toast-container` with styles dynamically. Is there a way to do this, for example:

```
const ToastContainerWrapper = styled.div`
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 300px;
`;

const ToastContainer = () => <ToastContainerWrapper id="toast-container" />;
```

Comment: Are you using `react-toastify`? If so, any reason you're not just using the provided `ToastContainer` component? The API already lets you set the notifications' position and width.

Answer (score -1):

I have not worked with styled-components. IMHO if you want to create

```
<div id="toast-container"></div>
```

in your HTML page dynamically, you can do that using normal dom functions. It should be done before rendering your component in div tag.

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
   const toastContainer = document.createElement('div');
   toastContainer.id = 'toast-container';
   document.body.appendChild(toastContainer); //Here the toast-container is directly inserted in the body tag.

   ReactDOM.render(<RComp/>, toastContainer);
});
```

Comment: The questions specifically asks using styled-components and would prefer to keep answers relevant.

Comment: @JoeTidee, I think styled-components returns a react-component. Therefore you are indirectly asking, how to create the html container dynamically in your HTML to include your react-app.